# Can't compile text file because of metafont?

Tags: errors, metafont, minionpro

i have a complex thesis template, which i can't seem to compile.
This is the output of pdftex
:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/mt-MinionPro.cfg)

Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\j '
(microtype)                in font encoding `T1' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/201(protrusion)'.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./Bishop-thesis.out) (./Bishop-thesis.out) (./abstract.tex
kpathsea: Running mktextfm MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation M for MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1.
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1
! I can't find file `MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1'.
<*> ...1; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...1; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1' failed to make MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/17.28=MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1 at 17.28pt not loadable
: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.5 {\Large
            Circuit Quantum Electrodynamics}\\
```

I think the cruicial part is :

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation M for MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1.
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1
! I can't find file `MinionPro-Subh-osf-t1'.
```

i already installed Minion Pro following [these](http://codealamode.blogspot.de/2012/08/installing-minionpro-for-latex-on-mac.html) instructions and i could compile the example file on the very same page.

Maybe it's important : I'm on a mac.

Comment: Did try compiling with XeLaTeX ? With `fontspec`it manages any system font very simply. As you can't use opentype fonts for maths, what I do in such a case is loading fontspec with the `no-math`option, and MinionPro with the `onlymath`option.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to compile [http://www.levbishop.org/thesis/](http://www.levbishop.org/thesis/). You need the MinionPro Font, packaged for `pdflatex` for that. Take a look at [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro), which is a program, that helps you to convert the OpenType Minion Pro to Type 1.

Comment: Do you have the optical fonts (Caption, Regular, Subhead, Display)? I guess not. Remove the `opticals` option of the `MinionPro` package loading. Also I can recommend [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) `;)` but if everything works for you, you won't necessarily need it.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes.. thats the template i'm trying to compile. I'll try FontPro and will report, as so i have results.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: I was able to compile it after installing the Font with FontPro